# difference post structure in .net core 2.2 and 3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, postman

in my project with .net core 2.2 i use postman to test APIs.
in postman
(1) set content-type: application/json
(2) body => raw & json
and i send simple JavaScript object like this:

```
{
    pageSize : 10,
    pageNumber : 0,
    sortType : 'nn',
    keyword : 'ff',
    cityCode : 1,
    citySlug : 'f',
    priceRange : 'ff',
    starRange : 'fff',
    hotelFacilityRange : 'fffff',
    roomFacilityRange : 'fs',
    hotelGroup : 'dss',
    hotelType : 'sss',
    foodType : 'ss'
}
```

but yesterday i upgrade to .net core 3.0
and now i must send json string, and doesn't accept simple object.
what is wrong?
when i send simple object i get null in api, but when i convert to json "pageSize" : 10, "pageNumber": 0 ... it works!!!

Comment: it shold work! can you post API method?

Comment: not realy, but when i change to json ("pageSize" ...), it works, something changes in .net coore 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but yesterday i upgrade to .net core 3.0 and now i must send json string, and doesn't accept simple object.

Indeed. I could reproduce the same issue as yours. But I don't think that's a bug because ASP.NET Core 3.0 now uses `System.Text.Json` as the default tool to serialize/deserialize json. See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support).

However, according to [json.org](http://json.org/), the string should start with `"` instead of `'`. :

[image: JSON string]
<sub>(source: [json.org](https://www.json.org/img/string.png))</sub>

In short, **the way you did in old days is not a standard JSON representation**. The reason why you can do that is [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) does it for you automatically.

---

To enable the old behavior, you could follow [Microsoft's advice here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support):

1. Add a package reference to [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson)
2. Add `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` for MVC:

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
 }
```